# LLVM backend for a custom 19 bit processor

Tags: llvm, backend

Is it possible to create an LLVM target backend for a custom 19-bit processor, without having to write too much code in the LLVM source? Is this a correct DataLayout for LLVM, or it has to be multiples of 8-bit, e.g., 16 or 32?

```
DataLayout("e-p:19:19-a19:19")
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not only the 19 bits though... Doesn't this custom CPU have its own instruction set? Register set? Addressing modes? ABI?

For a new target CPU, you have to implement a new `Target` in LLVM. See http://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html and http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html to get started.

Comment: Yes, it does have its own instructions and registers, but that's something I can manage. I meant to know if it's too much work or not? because it's 19-bit.